# Custom editor in MPS

Tags: dsl, mps

I have an concept in Jetbrains MPS which I would like to create a custom editor for.

The concept have a number of children.

For each child I would like to display the child's own editor but with a "-" in front of it.

I'm not completely sure I'm trying to solve this in the right way.

But my first attempt is a custom cell looping over the child nodes.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to find the editor cell of the child nodes:

My cell provider:

```
return new AbstractCellProvider(node) {
@Override
public EditorCell createEditorCell(EditorContext ctx) {
  EditorCell_Collection cells = EditorCell_Collection.createVertical(ctx, node);
  foreach n in node.elements {  
    EditorCell_Collection a = EditorCell_Collection.createHorizontal(ctx, node);
    EditorCell_Label label = new EditorCell_Constant(ctx, node, "-");
    a.addEditorCell(label);
    cells.addEditorCell(a);

       how to add the child node's editor here? 

   }
return cells;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you really trying to achieve? An example might help here...
Without further context (so I may misunderstand your problem), I think you could use an EditorComponent (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/mps/editor.html#editorcomponentsandeditorcomponentcells) for the original editor and then make an editor with a "-" constant followed by the EditorComponent to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks, I''ll try that. What I'm doing is rather simple. I have a number of concepts which I would like to behave differently when used as childs to a list concept. I woule like them to render a bit differently in the editor when used as list members.

Comment: In that case an alternate cell (if) with a condition in it based on a smodel query might help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I did not manage to get the custom editor cell to work properly, for instance pressing insert did not work. I have now implemented another ugly workaround instead